# Where should this loop be placed?

Tags: model-view-controller, language-agnostic

In an MVC application, I have an array of arrays(rows) being sent to the controller from the view. All rows from the array will represent a row in the database.

I'm stuck at the point where:
- I can define a function, that accepts the array of all rows, in the model and loop the rows there.
- Or I can define a function that accepts a single row, and call it in a loop in the controller.

Which method is the right(from a MVC point of view) one?

EDIT:
The question is should I do:
`$model->insertData($arrayOfRows);`
or
`foreach($arrayOfRows as $row) {

 $model->insertRow($row);

}`

Comment: Controller only passes the values. Handling of them should happen in the model layer. From you vague explanation - most likely the loop would be at the service-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using the first solution:
`$model->insertData($arrayOfRows);`
and loop the array of rows inside the model.

Answer (score 0):

In a proper MVC application, your data would not be coming from the view and going to the controller in the first place.

Your data should live inside the model. Your database connection and all data pulled from it should be represented by model objects and should only be exposed to the view/controller when needed for presentation (e.g., to visualize the data) or to make application-level decisions that are data-dependent.

Comment: By coming from the view I meant that this information was submitted for insertion in the database.

Comment: Gotcha. My mistake.

In that case you would want to pass the data straight through to the model (perhaps through the controller, depending on how you have things set up), and the model should do the work of looping over the input data, connecting to the database, and inserting the new data in the appropriate database format.

Answer (score -1):

You try the pattern below,

```
var $arr = [];

$arr.push($row); /*insert all rows to an array */

then from the jquery $.post, set the array to the parameter like,

$.post(
    '<controller/action>',
    { m: "[" + $arr + "]" },
    function (data){}
);
```